# after ajax complete, load <script> tags but only ones with specific id's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently using infinite-scroll to load more content, the content has `<script>` tags that need to be ran.  So I'm using the code below as an `ajax-callback`:

**JS** on load ajax callback:

```
function ajaxLoadedCallback() {
      // contentElem is the HTML element you've loaded via ajax
      scriptx = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

      // Load scripts into new array because 
      // scriptx seems to change as scripts execute, at least in some browsers
    scripts = new Array();
    for (var idx=0; idx<scriptx.length; idx++) {

        if (jQuery(scriptx[idx]).is("#inline-comments")) {
                scripts[idx] = scriptx[idx].text;
        }

    }

        console.log (scripts[idx]);
      // execute each script in turn
      for(idx=0; idx<scripts.length; ++idx) {
         if (scripts[idx].length!=0) {
            try {
              // create a function for the script & execute it
              f = new Function(scripts[idx]);
              f();
            } catch(se) {

            } // end try-catch
         } // end if
      } // end for

}
```

Each content post has this script tag I want to load:

```
<script id="inline-comments" >
    console.log ('<?php echo $post->ID; ?>' + 'has loaded...');
    var tid_<?php echo $post->ID; ?> = setInterval( function () {
    if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) return;
        clearInterval( tid_<?php echo $post->ID; ?> );       
        inline_comments_ajax_load(<?php echo $post->ID; ?>)
    }, 100 );   
</script>
```

Getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  error on this line: `if (scripts[idx].length!=0) {`

The ajax call back loads at the right time, but breaks because I assume `scripts[idx]` is empty. but why?  when I use `console.log()` it shows when the `scriptx[idx]` has an id and the name of the id.

**UPDATE** Thank you PSL!
`console.log` shows that it is finding the scripts, but scripts.length is returning zero

```
function ajaxLoadedCallback() {
    scriptx = document.getElementsByTagName("script");


    scripts = new Array();
    for (var idx=0; idx<scriptx.length; idx++) {

        if (jQuery(scriptx[idx]).is(".inline-comments-script")) {
            console.log (".inline-comments-scriptfound!");
            console.log ("####### .text #######");
            console.log (scriptx[idx].text);
            console.log ("####### .innerHTML ######");
            console.log (scriptx[idx].innerHTML);
            scripts.push = scriptx[idx].innerHTML;
        }

    }
    console.log ("####### END ######");
    console.log ("Found "+scripts.length+ " script(s)");

      // execute each script in turn
      for(idx=0; idx<scripts.length; ++idx) {
        var content = scripts[idx];
            if (content.length) {
                try {
              // create a function for the script & execute it
              f = new Function(content);
              f();
            } catch(se) {

            } // end try-catch
         } // end if
      } // end for

}
```

Works now! See PSL's answer below - you can also see it live if you have wordpress: https://github.com/MattMcFarland/inline-ajax-comments - works great!

Comment: Instead of iterating over all script elements use `document.getElementById('inline-comments');`

Comment: Tried that didnt work

Comment: Change `scripts.push = scriptx[idx].innerHTML;` to `scripts.push( scriptx[idx].innerHTML);` see my answer for syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple of issues here.

```
for (var idx=0; idx<scriptx.length; idx++) {

        if (jQuery(scriptx[idx]).is("#inline-comments")) {
                scripts[idx] = scriptx[idx].text;
        }

    }
```

You are incrementing the loop iteration variable eventhough there is no match and you dont want to push any item to the array. So if the first script does not match your condition `scripts[0]` will be undefined hence you get the error when you tru to acces the property `length` of undefined in your condition `if (scripts[idx].length!=0) {`

Another issue is that `scriptx[idx].text` here text is a function so you want the real text of the element and not the function reference so you should write `jQuery(scriptx[idx]).text()` or `scriptx[idx].innerHTML`. Since you are using id and ids are not supposed to be duplicated you can simply write this as:

```
     var txt = jQuery('#inline-comments').text();
     if (txt.length) {
        try {
          // create a function for the script & execute it
          f = new Function(scripts[idx]);
          f();
        } catch(se) {

        } // end try-catch
     } // end if
```

If you plan to turn `inline-comments` to class from id and you are looking to access multiple of them then this should work.

```
 scripts = [];
    for (var idx=0; idx<scriptx.length; idx++) {
        if (jQuery(scriptx[idx]).is(".inline-comments")) {
                scripts.push(scriptx[idx].innerHTML);
        }
     }
     // execute each script in turn
      for(idx=0; idx<scripts.length; ++idx) {
          var content = scripts[idx];
         if (content.length) {
            try {
              // create a function for the script & execute it
              f = new Function(content);
              f();
            } catch(se) {

            } // end try-catch
         } // end if
      } // end for
```

Comment: scripts.length is returning zero, you can see I edited my post and put console.log, it is finding the scripts properly (I renamed the id made it a class) but why is scripts.length zero?

Comment: @MatthewA.McFarland Yeah your syntax for pushing to array is incorrect. Try `scripts.push(scriptx[idx].innerHTML)`

Comment: oh duh thanks!  Also why does if (content.length) = true?  Interesting and I like that method.  Also, what is the difference between .text and .innerHTML, they look the same on my console but using .innerHTML in good faith!

Comment: You are welcome... :) content.length returns 0 or more so if it is 0 it is falsy else it is truthy so no need to explicitly cast it to boolean by comparing. `.text()` is a method on jquery object, `.innerHTML` is a property of dom element i.e native element property. both are almost same with some differences you can read that out...